# Resizing vertical and horizontal images in CSS

Tags: css, dynamic, resize

Html

```
<section class="rama">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/rama_detail.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/rama_detail2.jpg"/></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
section img {
    max-height:500px;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

So here's my problem. I want to dynamically resize both those images. `width:100%; height:auto;` work great for the horizontal image, but the vertical images width stretch out because of the `width:100%;`. Is there a simple way to dynamically resize both vertical and horizontal images without using different classes for both image type?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think so.. best I can think of is: either use subclasses so you won't have to put all the other declarations in both CSS rules, or: use JS (preferably jQuery) to add the different classes on pageload by checking whether width or height is bigger

Comment: CSS by itself cannot distinguish between landscape or portrait aspect ratios of images, so you need to use JS/jQuery to apply the right CSS rules to get he effect that you neeed.  I agree with @myfunkyside earlier comment.

Comment: @MarcAudet Alright, thank you. How would a jquery code for that would look like though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to use jQuery to iterate over the images, and dynamically add the appropriate class:

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M5Y53/4/**

---

**CSS**

```
section img {overflow:hidden;}
section img.landscape {max-width:200px; width:100%; height:auto;}
section img.portrait {max-height:200px; width:auto; height:100%;}
```

I split up the declarations for the landscape and portrait images in subclasses, so the rest of the declarations (in this case only `overflow:hidden;` don't have to be repeated for both subclasses.

**JS** (jQuery)

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    $('section img').each(function(){ //you need to put this inside the window.onload-function (not document.ready), otherwise the image dimensions won't be available yet
        if ($(this).width()/$(this).height() >= 1) {
            $(this).addClass('landscape');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('portrait');
        }
    });
});
```

Now, using jQuery, you iterate over each image that fits the `section img`-selector, and dynamically add the appropriate class. To determine whether the image has landscape or portrait format, simply check to see if width/height is larger (or equal) to 1.

---

I wasn't exactly sure how you wanted the images scaled, so I put `max-width:200px` and `max-height:200px` inside the subclasses, but you could also scale them to their parent-width and -height (see the commented-out CSS rule for the `.rama ul li`).

Comment: This is great! Though it doesn't work on chrome for some reason... The images loses there ratios when I resize the window. Any idea why? Or a possible fix?

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine for me on resize, in Chrome. Can you post a screenshot, maybe I can get some insight on the problem from that?

Comment: Here's a screenshot. Chrome on the left and explorer to the right.

[link](http://imgur.com/gX79Oui)

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, been REALLY busy, still am. And I still don't understand the problem. Only thing I can think of that might circumvent the problem, is putting the images in a container 'div' and set the width and height of that container. And remove the 'max-width' and 'max-height' from the image in the CSS. Sorry I can't be of more help